# Как заносятся переменные в массив $_REQUEST?

Tags: php

Привет.

Вопрос по `PHP`. Хочу "поиграть" с `$_REQUEST`. Для этого передаю данные одновременно методами *GET* и *POST*, при этом, в первом случае устанавливаю `variables_order` в "`GP`" через `.htaccess`, во втором - наоборот ("`PG`"). Ожидал, что в одном случае в массиве $_REQUEST буду "Vasia", "35" (вводил руками в форму), а в другом - "John","25" (взялось из ?name=John&age=25). Но ПОЛУЧИЛ то, что ВСЕГДА в массив $_REQUEST идут переменные из массива `$_POST`- "Vasia", "35".

```
<form action="\2.php?name=John&age=25" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
       <input type="text" name="age"><br/>
       <input type="submit"><br/>
</form>
<?php
   echo ini_get("variables_order");;
   echo "</br>";

   echo "Name:",$_GET["name"];
   echo "</br>";
   echo "Age:",$_GET["age"];
   echo "</br>";

   echo "Name:",$_POST["name"];
   echo "</br>";
   echo "Age:",$_POST["age"];
   echo "</br>";


   echo "Name:",$_REQUEST["name"];
   echo "</br>";
   echo "Age:",$_REQUEST["age"];
   echo "</br>";

?>
```

Comment: Знаю только одно - нездорово делать GET приоритетнее чем POST

Comment: я просто хочу "поиграть" этими штуками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вы не учли содержимое директивы **request_order**:

> Эта директива регулирует порядок, в котором PHP добавляет переменные GET, POST и Cookie в массив _REQUEST. Добавление производится слева направо, новые значения перезаписывают старые.
>
> **Если значение этой директивы не установлено, то используется значение директивы variables_order** для содержимого переменной $_REQUEST.
>
> Учтите, что файлы php.ini, поставляемые с дистрибутивом, по соображениям безопасности не содержат значение 'C' (cookies).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, оценил его. сработало. зачем придумали ДВЕ диревтивы (request_order и variables_order), которые регулируют порядок занесения переменныех из суперглобальных массивов в $_REQUEST? по-моему, хватило бы и одного варианта - либо request_order , либо variables_order

Comment: @Dimon, `variables_order` служит для создания суперглобальных массивов, а `request_order` для заполнения `$_REQUEST`.